# genus one curves bundle over complex torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, fibre-bundles

Let $M$ be a holomorphic fiber bundle over torus $\mathbb C^2/\Lambda$ whose fibers are curves of genus one. Is there any classification about such $M$ ?

When the fibers are given by $\mathbb P^1$ instead of curves of genus one, every $\mathbb P^1$-bundle can be obtained by taking projective spaces of the fiber of a vector bundle. This helps to classify.In genus one case, does there exist a similar argument ? i.e: every possible $M$ can be obtained by dropping the line quotient from a line bundle over  $\mathbb C^2/\Lambda$?

Comment: Do you mean elliptic curves or genus one curves? I.e. does the fiber bundle come with a section?

Comment: What is this correspondence between $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundles and $\mathbb{C}^*$-bundles?

Comment: The $j$-invariant of the fiber should be  holomorphic on the torus and thus constant. Depending on the $j$-invariant, the automorphism group of the elliptic curve is $\mathbb{Z}/2$, $\mathbb{Z}/4$  or $\mathbb{Z}/6$. So it seems to me that you just need to classify $\mathbb{Z}/n$-torsors.

Comment: @abx Every vector bundle over a base space X gives a projective bundle by taking the projective spaces of the fibers, and all projective bundles arise in this way when we consider $\mathbb P^1$ over $\mathbb C^2/ \Lambda$

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I mean genus one curves.  but I don't know the differences between genus one curves and elliptic curves

Comment: @LennartMeier Be careful: the Hopf surface $(\mathbf{C}^2\setminus 0)/q^\mathbf{Z}$ is fibered over the simply connected $(\mathbf{C}^2\setminus 0)/\mathbf{C}^* \simeq \mathbf{P}^1$ with fibers isomorphic to the fixed genus one curve $\mathbf{C}^*/q^\mathbf{Z}$. So classifying families of genus one curves (as opposed to elliptic curves) is harder (note that the family above does not admit a section).

Comment: Chicken feed: so you mean rank 2 vector bundle, not $\Bbb{C}^*$-bundle.

Comment: @Chickenfeed: an elliptic curve is a smooth curve of genus one with a marked point. Without the marked point, it is not an elliptic curve, as it has no identity element for its holomorphic abelian group operation.

Comment: You'll find a detailed study of these bundles in *Compact complex surfaces* by Barth-Hulek-Peters-Van de Ven, §V.5.